# Program slowing down a lot when replaced variable usage with a literal, why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization

I was trying to optimize my solution for [this challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2ip1gj/10082014_challenge_183_intermediate_edge_matching/). After noticing that one of the other solutions used a nice trick - changing `size` to a compile-time template parameter, I wanted to check myself how it would speed up the code.

I was compiling from MSVC2013 with Release configuration. Here is the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef std::vector<char*> Board;

int size;

void rotate(char *str){
    char temp = str[0];
    str[0] = str[1];
    str[1] = str[2];
    str[2] = str[3];
    str[3] = temp;
}

inline char fastToLower(char c){    //actually it's toUpper but whatever
    return (c - 65) % 32;
}

bool checkLeftEdge(Board::iterator begin, Board::iterator right){
    if ((right - begin) % size == 0)
        return true;
    auto left = right - 1;
    char c1 = (*right)[3], c2 = (*left)[1];
    return fastToLower(c1) == fastToLower(c2) && c1 != c2;
}

bool checkTopEdge(Board::iterator begin, Board::iterator bottom){
    auto top = bottom - size;
    if (top < begin)
        return true;
    char c1 = (*bottom)[0], c2 = (*top)[2];
    return fastToLower(c1) == fastToLower(c2) && c1 != c2;
}

bool isLastElementValid(Board::iterator begin, Board::iterator last){
    return
        checkTopEdge(begin, last) &&
        checkLeftEdge(begin, last);
}

bool recurse(Board::iterator begin, Board::iterator end, Board::iterator len){
    if (len == end)
        return true;
    for (auto it = len; it != end; ++it){
        std::swap(*len, *it);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            if (isLastElementValid(begin, len)){
                bool ret = recurse(begin, end, len + 1);
                if (ret == true)
                    return ret;
            }
            rotate(*len);
        }
        std::swap(*len, *it);
    }
    return false;
}

void draw(const Board &board){
    for (int y = 0; y < size; ++y){
        cout << std::string(size * 4 + 1, '-') << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
            cout << "| " << board[to_index(x, y)][0] << " ";
        cout << "|" << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
            cout << "|" << board[to_index(x, y)][3] << " " << board[to_index(x, y)][1];
        cout << "|" << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
            cout << "| " << board[to_index(x, y)][2] << " ";
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    cout << std::string(size * 4 + 1, '-') << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    std::ifstream in ("in.txt");
    if (!in)
        return 1;

    in >> size;
    Board board(size * size);
    for (auto& ptr : board){
        ptr = new char[4];
        in.ignore();
        in.read(ptr, 4);
    }   

    auto success = recurse(board.begin(), board.end(), board.begin());
    if (success)
        draw(board);

    for (auto& ptr : board)
        delete []ptr;

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

With this set of sample data:

```
5
ckck
yYcc
YcCK
kKCM
CMKc
cKYC
kYcm
KYyY
Mccm
yKcm
mykK
MMCm
ckYC
ycmm
MmKM
kymc
KMMK
KcyM
kYck
YCKM
myYm
kYyY
CMKM
yYCM
YKyk
```

The program ran for 11.5 seconds.

When I replaced

```
bool checkTopEdge(Board::iterator begin, Board::iterator bottom){
    auto top = bottom - size;
```

with

```
    auto top = bottom - 5;
```

The program ran for a bit under 10 seconds.

But when I replaced:

```
bool checkLeftEdge(Board::iterator begin, Board::iterator right){
    if ((right - begin) % size == 0)
```

with

```
    if ((right - begin) % 5 == 0)
```

The time increased to 16 seconds!

I've took a peek into the disassembly, and noticed that `isLastElementValid` function was no longer inlined, although `checkLeftEdge` and `checkTopEdge` still were.

The modified part of the code doesn't seem to have changed much:

```
0138136C  mov         eax,ecx  
0138136E  sub         eax,esi  
01381370  sar         eax,2  
01381373  cdq  
01381374  idiv        eax,ebx  
01381376  test        edx,edx  
01381378  je          recurse+0E2h (013813B2h)
```

with 5 literal:

```
00B4133D  mov         eax,ecx  
00B4133F  mov         esi,5  
00B41344  sub         eax,edx  
00B41346  sar         eax,2  
00B41349  cdq  
00B4134A  idiv        eax,esi  
00B4134C  test        edx,edx  
00B4134E  je          isLastElementValid+0CAh (0B4139Ah)
```

So my problem is: I don't see how the changes I've made caused the program to slow down. And even if MSVC for whatever reason decided to no longer inline one of the functions, I can't believe this alone caused a 50% increase in run time.

Comment: *"First of all, I'm sorry that I didn't simplify the code, but I was afraid that it could make the issue no longer appear."* But isn't this the point? When the issue no longer appears, then you have isolated the issue.

Comment: Heh, true, it is indeed about this exact code behaving weirdly in these exact circumstances. I was just worried that someone might say it's too long to analyze or something. I will remove that line.

Comment: As I read your question you have already done a good analysis what your compiler optimizes under which circumstances. So what is your question? We can't improve your compiler and I believe that here is nobody who knows which algorithm and parameters are used to select the actual optimizing strategy. If you need really fast code you always have to use a profiler and shift the things a bit around to get optimal results. But again: What is now your question?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why I hate the "which is faster" type questions, and always tell people to measure for themselves. Today's compilers and CPUs have far too many variables to give out blanket advice.

Comment: I've accepted by now that common sense doesn't always apply when trying to optimize the code. My only question is, is there anything going on besides that disabled inlining that I haven't noticed that gives a 50% slowdown. I expected at worst a barely noticeable change, not a 50% one.

Answer (score 1):

That actually was caused by linining. I've checked that by adding `__declspec(noinline)` to isLastElementValid, which indeed caused a 50% loss.

Forcing inlining with `__forceinline` solves my issue.